# Semitransparent background image (PNG24) for UINavigationBar only shows transparent after rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I'm using a category to implement a custom background for `UINavigationBar`.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TopNav-YellowRule.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

}
@end
```

The image that I am using is a semitransparent PNG24. When the app loads the background of the `UINavigationBar` shows up just fine but is not semitransparent - I cannot see the views that are below the `UINavigationBar`.

When I rotate the device, however, the image is suddenly semitransparent and works just fine. Any ideas what is happening on rotate that is allow the image to display as intended? Is there a way to fix it so that it displays properly on initial load, before a rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after @end. See if it helps

```
navgationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: It seems that setting either backgroundColor or tintColor to clearColor does the trick, except that I had to set it twice. Setting it either before or after didn't work. I wonder if there is a better solution?

Comment: Try not to use tint color, Why would you have to set it twice? Can you show me how you are using this?